# Pandas DataFrame: expanding data to full month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, date-range

I got data of monthly time tracking bookings. Since there are no bookings for weekends nor national holidays, the data is missing some days. Now I'm expanding the data so that it includes all days of that month but simply with null data. Here's how I solved it. I wonder if there is a more elegant way to achieve the same thing?

Sample input data indexed for column `start`:

```
+---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+
| start               | from   | to    | paused   |   hours_working |   error |
|---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------|
| 2019-11-04 00:00:00 | 08:30  | 18:00 | 00:30    |               9 |       0 |
| 2019-11-05 00:00:00 | 09:30  | 19:00 | 00:30    |               9 |       0 |
| 2019-11-06 00:00:00 | 09:00  | 18:00 | 01:00    |               8 |       0 |
+---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+
```

Then I'm retrieving the first timestamp that I then use to create a period/index for the full month:

```
# get first day of the month
first_timestamp = df.index[0].replace(day=1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# build an index containing all days of that month
index_month = pd.date_range(start=first_timestamp, periods=pd.Period(first_timestamp).days_in_month, freq="24H")
index_month
```

Resulting in:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2019-11-01', '2019-11-02', '2019-11-03', '2019-11-04',
               '2019-11-05', '2019-11-06', '2019-11-07', '2019-11-08',
               '2019-11-09', '2019-11-10', '2019-11-11', '2019-11-12',
               '2019-11-13', '2019-11-14', '2019-11-15', '2019-11-16',
               '2019-11-17', '2019-11-18', '2019-11-19', '2019-11-20',
               '2019-11-21', '2019-11-22', '2019-11-23', '2019-11-24',
               '2019-11-25', '2019-11-26', '2019-11-27', '2019-11-28',
               '2019-11-29', '2019-11-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='24H')
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't figure out how to join the index (date range) with the original data. Therefore, I had to create a new empty data frame with the new index and join that data frame with the original data.

```
df_index = pd.DataFrame(index_month, columns=['start'])
df_index.set_index('start', inplace=True)

df_month = df_index.join(df).reset_index()

from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df_month, headers='keys', tablefmt='psql'))
```

Giving me the final result:

```
+----+---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+
|    | start               | from   | to    | paused   |   hours_working |   error |
|----+---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------|
|  0 | 2019-11-01 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  1 | 2019-11-02 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  2 | 2019-11-03 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  3 | 2019-11-04 00:00:00 | 08:30  | 18:00 | 00:30    |               9 |       0 |
|  4 | 2019-11-05 00:00:00 | 09:30  | 19:00 | 00:30    |               9 |       0 |
|  5 | 2019-11-06 00:00:00 | 09:00  | 18:00 | 01:00    |               8 |       0 |
|  6 | 2019-11-07 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  7 | 2019-11-08 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  8 | 2019-11-09 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
|  9 | 2019-11-10 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 10 | 2019-11-11 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 11 | 2019-11-12 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 12 | 2019-11-13 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 13 | 2019-11-14 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 14 | 2019-11-15 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 15 | 2019-11-16 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 16 | 2019-11-17 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 17 | 2019-11-18 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 18 | 2019-11-19 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 19 | 2019-11-20 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 20 | 2019-11-21 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 21 | 2019-11-22 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 22 | 2019-11-23 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 23 | 2019-11-24 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 24 | 2019-11-25 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 25 | 2019-11-26 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 26 | 2019-11-27 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 27 | 2019-11-28 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 28 | 2019-11-29 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
| 29 | 2019-11-30 00:00:00 | nan    | nan   | nan      |             nan |     nan |
+----+---------------------+--------+-------+----------+-----------------+---------+
```

So, what's wrong about that? Nothing, the result is fine. But I wonder if there is a better way to create the index for that month and then on how to join that index with the original data? Any suggestions? Just wanna learn and get better ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all values of `DatetimeIndex` are unique, here is possible use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) - also for start and end of new `DatetimeIndex` is first convert first value to month Period and then used [`Period.to_timestamp`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html):

```
first_per = df.index[0].to_period('m')

# build an index containing all days of that month
index_month = pd.date_range(start=first_per.to_timestamp(how='start'), 
                            end=first_per.to_timestamp(how='end'),
                            freq="24H",
                            name='start')

df = df.reindex(index_month).reset_index()
print (df.head(10))
       start   from     to paused  hours_working  error
0 2019-11-01    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
1 2019-11-02    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
2 2019-11-03    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
3 2019-11-04  08:30  18:00  00:30            9.0    0.0
4 2019-11-05  09:30  19:00  00:30            9.0    0.0
5 2019-11-06  09:00  18:00  01:00            8.0    0.0
6 2019-11-07    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
7 2019-11-08    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
8 2019-11-09    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
9 2019-11-10    NaN    NaN    NaN            NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Amazing. Much shorter and I learned about `to_period`, `to_timestamp` and `reindex`. Didn't know those methods before. Thx.